# Missing Script in WebSphere 7.0

Tags: websphere, profiles

The book and video tutorials that i am following for WebSphere Administration talks about "pmt.sh" script and how to use it.

However, in my WebSphere installation on Linux which is WAS 7.0 [not a ND package] I do not find any "pmt.sh" script.

Can you please let me know the equivalent script of the same and some idea about why it is missing in my Install?

Comment: Did you check in `app_server_root/bin/ProfileManagement` folder?

Answer (score 0):

The pmt.sh tool is not available on 64 bit systems.

You will need to use the manage profiles command line tool instead. See the link below to learn how to get and use the interactive wrapper for the command line tool, which makes the command line tool more user friendly.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21442487